# Every time when I Run project I got this /**/ this is so annoying, How can I get rid it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Here is my code

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                        <MatSelect Label="Course" Class="col-md-12" Outlined="true" @bind-Value="@obj.CourseId">

                            @foreach (var item in CourseList)
                                {
                                <MatOption TValue="int" Value="@item.CourseId"> @item.CourseName</MatOption>
                                }
                            /**/
                            /**/
                            /**/
                            /**/
                            /**/
                        </MatSelect>
                    </div>
```

When I run the project, I automatically get this in my code. I use CodeMaid, after disable codeMaid I still got this. What can I do now ??

Comment: Is this in your real code or in the .g.cs file ?

Comment: I had the same issue in some components containing table. I guess it was because they was to big and the issue practically disappeared after I split them in much smaller components

Comment: In my case it occured when I edited a part of the html code or I formatted it using CTRL  E + D not when I ran it, And I don't use CodeMaid.

Comment: @aguafrommars What Can I do now to get rid of this issue temporarily?

Comment: @HenkHolterman No !!

Comment: You should not answer an `a OR b`  question with No!

Comment: @SefatAnam refactor your code to smaller component

Comment: This could be tooling issue in VS. MS Stated they know that the current support in VS is really bad and buggy for Blazor.

Comment: @ZsoltBendes  I think so, Brother :)